# What should be the formal definition of continuous uniform distribution pdf value at upper bound?

Tags: distributions, uniform-distribution

What is the most formal (and coherent with probability theory) definition for the value of $f(b)$ where $b$ is the upper bound of the support of the continuos uniform distribution $\mathcal U(a,b) ?$
We can choose:

\begin{align}f(b)& = 1/(b-a) ~~\text{or}\\
 &= 0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{or}\\
 &= \text{undefined}.\end{align}

Comment: The first one. It's a uniform distribution, so the value is constant across its interval.

Comment: @AdrianKeister in any of these cases is a continuos uniform distribution.

Comment: *No* pdf is defined, as a function, at any point.  As a *convention,* a pdf is often represented as a function that is continuous wherever possible.  Because *no* pdf for this distribution can be continuous at either endpoint, it cannot be uniquely defined at either endpoint according to such a convention.  In this sense the last bullet is rigorously the answer, but the other two bullets are perfectly valid, too.

Comment: @whuber look here https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_1_1_pdf.php

Comment: if we define PDF as derivative of the CDF then the PDF is not defined in a, b

Comment: @frhack Sometimes, on a closed interval, the derivative is defined only from-the-left at the right-hand endpoint, and only from-the-right at the left-hand endpoint.

Comment: The PDF is defined as the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the probability measure with respect to Lebesgue measure.  A more elementary characterization of the PDF is that if there exists a function $f$ for which the distribution function $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(x)\mathrm{d}x,$ then $f$ is *a* PDF for $F.$ Even when you use elementary Riemann integration you may *arbitrarily* modify any such $f$ at a finite number of points without changing that defining relationship with $F.$ Your reference concerns only the restricted set of *absolutely continuous* distributions, btw.

Comment: @whuber therefore each of the three options is feasible.
What can we conclude?

Comment: One conclusion is that it is worthwhile understanding the nuances of how a PDF represents a density.

Answer (score 2):

Partially answered in comments:

> *No* pdf is defined, as a function, at any point.  As a *convention,* a pdf is often represented as a function that is continuous wherever possible.  Because *no* pdf for this distribution can be continuous at either endpoint, it cannot be uniquely defined at either endpoint according to such a convention.  In this sense the last bullet is rigorously the answer, but the other two bullets are perfectly valid, too.

> The PDF is defined as the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the probability measure with respect to Lebesgue measure.  A more elementary characterization of the PDF is that if there exists a function $f$ for which the distribution function $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(x)\mathrm{d}x,$ then $f$ is *a* PDF for $F.$ Even when you use elementary Riemann integration you may *arbitrarily* modify any such $f$ at a finite number of points without changing that defining relationship with $F.$ Your reference concerns only the restricted set of *absolutely continuous* distributions, btw.

> One conclusion is that it is worthwhile understanding the nuances of how a PDF represents a density.

– whuber